# SQL Check if table exists then Create Table & Insert into same query

Tags: mysql

Tried This Code But it gives "**ER_PARSE_ERROR**"

**Err Description**: "sqlMessage": "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Insert values ('Bitcoin')' at line 1"

```
var query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS projects (project_name VARCHAR(10)) Insert values ('" + projectName + "')";
```

I want to Insert a new Project in the Projects Table, create the table if it does not exists and insert the record, I can write multiple queries for this work and check response if success then proceed with the next query but I am looking for a query which does all the work concatenating multiple queries in itself.

Note: I am using mysql module in Nodejs

The process should work synchronously one after the other, when a user sends a post request to the route '/add_project' with data in body "project_name":"project1" then the server inserts the record in the mysql table projects but it generates err "No such Table " if that was the first record.
I want it to work synchronously first by creating the table if not exists and then inserting the record.

Edit: Added screenshot for @Nick suggestion
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Do you have a multithreaded setup, i.e. would you expect it to be possible for more than one thread in your application to execute the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements?

Comment: No, I only want the procedure to work synchronously one after the other, when a user sends a post request to the route '/add_project' with data in body "project_name":"project1" then the server inserts the record in the mysql table projects but it generates err "No such Table " if that was the first record. I want it to work synchronously first by creating the table if not exists and then inserting the record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`CREATE TABLE ... SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-select.html) syntax:

```
var query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS projects (project_name VARCHAR(10)) SELECT '" + projectName + "' AS project_name";
```

[Demo on rextester](https://rextester.com/YHPVB22838)

Comment: I want to insert a record into the table after creating the table select works when there are already some records in the table.

Comment: This query is not selecting records from a table, it is just selecting the string `projectName`. Have a look at my demo and you will see it starts from a non-existent table (because the first thing I do is `DROP` the table.

Comment: @nilanshbansal Sorry messed up my demo. It's working again now.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Working Code But I need to get less complicated code without much error handling:

```
app.post('/add_project_to_database',function(req,res){
var projectName = req.body.project_name;

//CHECK IF PROJECT EXISTS
var query = "Select project_name from projects where project_name = '" + projectName + "'";
return res.send('Project Already Exists!');

//INSERTING PROJECT
// var query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS projects (project_name VARCHAR(10)) Insert values ('" + projectName + "')";
var query = "Insert into projects(project_name) values ('" + projectName + "')";

con.query(query, function(err, result){
    if(err){
        var query_create = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS projects (project_name VARCHAR(10))";
        con.query(query_create,function(error,res_create){
            if(error){
                console.log(error);
                res.send(error);
            }
            else{
                console.log("TABlE CREATED");
                con.query(query,function(error_insert,response){
                    if(error_insert){
                        console.log(error_insert);
                        res.send(error_insert);
                    }
                    else{
                        console.log("RECORD INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY !");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }else{
        res.send("Successfully Inserted Project");
    }
});
});
```